# how to navigate fron one page to other in angularjs as soon as i click inside the textbox

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

my javascript file is

```
var todoModule = angular.module('ToDoModule', ['ngRoute','ngTable']) 
.config(function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            // route ToDo page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : "todo.tmpl.html",
                controller  : "ParentController"
            })

            // route for the Summary page
            .when('/summary', {
                templateUrl : 'summary.tmpl.html',
                controller  : 'SummaryController'
            })

            // route for the pendingtask page
            .when('/pendingtask',{
                templateUrl: 'pendingtask.tmpl.html',
                controller : 'pendingtaskController'
            })

            // route for details page
            .when('details',{
                templateUrl: 'details.tmpl.html',
                controller : 'detailsController'
            })

            // when anything else, just go to '/'
            .otherwise('/');
    })

.controller('detailsController',['$scope','ToDo',function($scope,ToDo)
    {

    }])
```

consider i am having index.html file and i have textbox there, if i click inside that textbox i should be able to navigate to details.tmpl.html file. Can any body help me. How can i use ng-Click directive here??? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `ng-click` to your textarea in html like this

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" ng-click="redirect()"></textarea>
```

then in your controller define your **redirect** function like this

```
$scope.redirect = function () {
   $location.path("/where/you/want/to/go");
}
```

but be aware in order to use **$location** in your controller you should inject it in your controller...

**UPDATE**

I add a working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/fcEB2NfQIXJUQhXt64nD?p=preview).

Comment: <input ng-model="task.name" ng-change="updateLastModified(task)" type="text" class="form-control" ng-click="redirect()">
its not working for me, any help??

Comment: @PratapA.K can you provide plunker?

Comment: insted of anchor tag in summary.tmpl.html page, i need to do this by clicking textbox.

Comment: @PratapA.K It seems your problem is input element is not rendered as expected maybe because of your ngTable directive maybe you should look somewhere else for the problem but I updated my answer as you want check it...

Answer (score 2):

Just use `$location.path('/details');` in your `ng-click` function :

```
.controller('detailsController',['$scope','$location',function($scope, $location) {
   $scope.redirect = function() {
      $location.path('/details');
   }
}])
```

By the way, reading the doc and googling it would have you make find this in less than 1 minute

Comment: <input ng-model="task.name" ng-change="updateLastModified(task)" type="text" class="form-control" ng-click="redirect()">
its not working for me, any help??

Comment: your plunker is way too large. Provide a minimalistic one with only your concern.

Comment: Modified..........http://plnkr.co/edit/P5oDRQAhPw8tJJco1oAy?p=preview

not working, any how if i click on the textbox i should be able to navigate to details.tmpl.html page.. any help??